# SQLite2 and Python DELETE not working

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-delete

I've gone over this several times and researched like crazy, but still cannot figure out why this SQL delete is not working.

```
if (devicedelete):
  print devicedelete
  conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  try:
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM DevicesDynamic WHERE DeviceName = ?', (devicename, ))
  except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print e.args[0]
  conn.commit()
  conn.close()
```

The code does display the value that I expect in the devicedelete variable, but it is not deleting from the database.

I am not receiving any errors.

I saw some queries that used three single quotes around the query, so I tried that with no difference in results.

Any thoughts here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you verify the content of the database? Are you sure you are not seeing some cached values?

Comment: At a guess, is there any leading or trailing whitespace on `devicename`?

Comment: I don't think there are any whitespaces.  I'm reading the data from the table to create the form that allows for deletion.  Here is the way the radio button is being formed: <td><input type="radio" name="devicedelete" value="Dan-Mac"/></td>. I would think the whitespace would show there if there was any.

Comment: I have been very careful to commit every call (other than select) to ensure there is no cached data.

Comment: I can insert into the database, so I know the permissions are good, and I can see the row in the database that I'm trying to delete.

Comment: I can also delete the row using the command-line sqlite3 interface.

Comment: Further to what @Code-Apprentice was saying; after `conn.commit()`, what do you get from `print(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DevicesDynamic WHERE DeviceName = ?", (devicename, )).fetchall()`. It's not clear _where_ you're seeing the value you want to delete.

Comment: Ah - I have a page that can add or delete an entry to the database.  The order is delete a device if delete device is defined, add a device if all of the necessary fields have data, and at the end of the page, it reads from the database to populate the delete form.

Comment: @roganjosh The query you gave me caused a HTTP 500 error on the Apache server.  I changed it to `print cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DevicesDynamic WHERE DeviceName = ?", (devicename, )).fetchall()` and it worked.  It provided an empty set, so I'm thinking it's not matching even though it should...

Comment: So it sounds like you are seeing the data that should have been deleted in the generated HTML UI. You should use the `sqlite3` command-line tool or a GUI database tool to check the actual data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to admit my rookie mistake - I used the wrong variable name to populate the query.  I'm plugging in devicename and the variable should be devicedelete.  After making the change, the code works as expected.

Thanks for the help, I'll be in the corner with my head hung in shame.